# bloquear o "apagamento" da tela por tempo de inatividade

Tags: java, android

Meu aplicativo funciona como um guia para um iluminador profissional, ele funciona de forma passiva(responde via Bluetooth a comandos do usuário em sua ferramenta de trabalho) ou de forma offline onde o usuário pode operá-lo manualmente em paralelo com sua ferramenta, 
a questão é que em ambas as ocasiões o usuário ficaria um bom tempo sem interagir com a aplicação, porém lendo seus dados constantemente, é essencial que a tela não apague nem escureça, sei que o usuário pode muito bem setar isso manualmente, mas eu queria fazer de dentro da aplicação.

procurei no Google mas só aparece besteiras, falando de app para poupar bateria e etc, o problema é que as palavras-chaves são as mesmas de várias dúvidas de leigos usuários.

procurei no site mas não achei nada aqui.

procurei no Developers da Google, porém por não saber muito bem inglês, e pela a explicação deles não ser muito intuitiva, não cheguei a resultados construtivos.
alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tente colocar isso no `onCreate` da sua `Activity`

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Ou dentro do seu layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
```

Caso queira ler mais sobre:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Espero que ajude!

Comment: deu certo cara valew;

Comment: Estranho, testei ambas as formas, no **Android 4.4.4 API 19** somente a opção `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` manteve a tela ativa, mas resolveu meu problema, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que vai precisar disto [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html), mas parece que a resposta acima também resolve na dúvida faz o teste com as duas em aparelhos diferentes.

Exite também a opção de fazer isso parcialmente [WakeLock Partial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)

```
//ONCREATE
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
wl.acquire(); //informa para nao desligar a tela

//quando sair da atividade ou do apk 
wl.release(); //informa que já esta liberado para desligar
```

Comment: no galaxy note 2 funcionou mas vou tentar em varios aparelhos antes de liberar, não apague sua resposta por favor, quando eu terminar de realizar os testes irei testar a sua tbm!

Comment: faz isso as vez os sistemas são customizados e pode variar de acordo com o fabricante do aparelho. Se tiver dispositivos para testar vale a pena e poupa tempo :)